# Strange behaviour in the loss graph of a CNN

Tags: python, keras

I have trained my ResNet50 network with 8 different classes and after it finished training I made the training and validation loss graph. Here is my result:

[image]

The training loss only appears halfway because I cut the y axis.

The strange thing happening is the validation loss always being smaller than the training loss. I don't know why that happens, could it be from using class weights? Or is it something else?

EDIT: The validation set is not a subset of the training set, I ran the folders in the programm `WinMerge` and they came out 100 % different, no images repeated.

What is even stranger is that the accuracy graph is according to normal(validation has a lower accuracy at the end) as you can see here:

[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
Resnet = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
model = tf.keras.Sequential(Resnet)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=no_classes, activation="softmax"))

checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='/content/check/Best_weigths_teste4.h5', save_weights_only=True,
                                                save_best_only=True,monitor='val_loss',
                                                mode='min',verbose=1) 

early_stop= tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',mode='min', patience=10)

class_weight = {0: 20262./693,
                1: 20262./2658,
                2: 20262./2099,
                3: 20262./191,
                4: 20262./3617,
                5: 20262./10300,
                6: 20262./502,
                7: 20262./202}   

History= model.fit(x=train_generator, epochs = 50, callbacks=[checkpoint, early_stop], validation_data=val_generator, class_weight=class_weight).history

#to plot loss and acc
plt.figure()
plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.xlabel("Epochs")
plt.ylim([0,5])
plt.plot(History['loss'])
plt.plot(History['val_loss'])
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper right')

plt.figure()
plt.ylabel("Accuracy (training and validation)")
plt.xlabel("Epochs")
plt.ylim([0,1])
plt.plot(History["accuracy"])
plt.plot(History["val_accuracy"])
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper right')
```

P.S: I don't know if this is relevant but this is how I create my generators(I use `flow_from directory`):

```
train_dataGen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=None,horizontal_flip=True,vertical_flip=True,
                                   preprocessing_function=rotate_image)
val_dataGen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=None)

train_generator = train_dataGen.flow_from_directory(directory="./novo2/train_pad_cc",
                                                    class_mode="categorical",
                                                    batch_size=32,
                                                    shuffle = True, seed = 1)

val_generator = val_dataGen.flow_from_directory(directory="./novo2/val_pad_cc",
                                                    class_mode="categorical",
                                                    batch_size=32,
                                                    shuffle = False, seed = 2)
```

Comment: Have you checked that none of the validation set is present in the training set? My hunch looking at that graph is that the validation data is a subset of the training data.

Comment: Yes, I know for a fact that the validation data is not a subset of the training data. I used the `split-folders.ratio` function to separate the images into training and validation and from what I know this function doesn't put the same image in two different places

Comment: @Oso I've also run the WinMerge programm and now I can say they are 100% different from each other. no images are repeated